# Getting "Permission denied" when running lighttpd on Android

Tags: android, lighttpd, permission-denied

I want to create an application like Palapa Web Server (apache php mysql). I want to use lighttpd. I got the sources, I built them for arm, and I made an app to download a ZIP file from my website and extract the content to `getFilesDir()`.

My problem is:

> 2019-03-04 21:58:13.203 9236-9236/package.webify E/Webify:
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "lighttpd" (in directory
>   "/data/user/0/package.webify/files/sbin"): error=13, Permission denied

What can I do to start the server? It has to work somehow, otherwise Palapa Web Server wouldn't work, which has the same principle.

Comment: Is `/data/user/0/package.webify/files/sbin/lighttpd` have `x` permission? If not, use `chmod +x` to grant permission.

Comment: I have tried this already. Still permission denied.

Comment: Run 'file' on the executable and validate that it is built for the correct architecture (including 32-bit or 64-bit).  Check 'file' on a different app on the phone and see if it matches the arch to which you cross-compiled lighttpd.

Comment: @asked , how you integrated lighttpd in android., can you please help me ?